# How to send data from Arduino Uno with SIM900 GPRS to Firebase

Tags: arduino-uno, shields, gps

I'm creating a real-time vehicle tracking Android application using the Arduino Uno and SIM900 GPS. I want to use Firebase as the database for the coordinates which will hold just the longitude and latitude. My question is about sending the data through the GPRS to Firebase. Right now I've only been able to use a terminal program to send AT commands to create a connection but I've been getting errors when connecting to firebase using AT+CIPSEND. I know that it only excepts https traffic so I've been trying commands from [here](http://www.jarzebski.pl/datasheets/SIM900_https-121018-1.00.pdf). Here is some code that I've tried:

```
AT
OK
AT+CREG?
+CREG: 0,1

OK
AT+CGATT?
+CGATT: 1

OK
AT+CIPSTATUS
OK

STATE: IP INITIAL
AT+CIPMUX=0
OK
AT+CSTT="att.mvno","",""
OK
AT+CIICR
OK
AT+CIPSTART="TCP","https://mygpstracker.firebaseio.com","80"
OK
CONNECT OK
```

and

```
AT+CIPSHUT
OK
AT+CIPSTART="TCP","https://mygpstracker.firebaseio.com","443"
OK
CONNECT OK
```

If I use CIPSEND, how should my message be formatted to send lat or long in a way Firebase can interpret?
Or am I going about this in a convoluted manner? Is there an easier way? I appreciate any help/comment. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like you said, Firebase only accepts HTTPS traffic, which the Arduino Uno cant generate. Your HTTP requests first need to be sent through a proxy server that supports SSL, before being sent on to your Firebase database using a PUT or POST request. [This site](http://www.devacron.com/arduino-firebase/) explains how to do everything from setting up your own proxy server to writing the GPS data (in your case) to Firebase. You may want to look at alternatives if this is too tedious for your purposes.

Answer (score -1):

just remove "https://" its working